# Debug SSH not connecting

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, debian, ssh-keys

I am trying to connect to the remote server using ssh, but I have `Permission denied (publickey).`.

I've gone through all possible reasons I can suggest and other questions suggest.

- I am sure that my key is correct, I checked many times and I am able to login to the target server from other machine using that key;
- I set rights on a file to 700

Well, what gives `ssh -v`:

```
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for fmbnew
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to --myhost-- [--myip--] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file "~/.ssh/host-key" type -1
debug1: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 
Debian-5+deb8u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Host '--myhost--' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: "~/.ssh/host-key"
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

And this is what found in the `auth.log` on the server (not much):

```
Apr  1 12:15:33 host-07 sshd[23955]: Connection closed by --my-client-ip-- [preauth]
```

I should say that this client machine is pretty old, it has Centos 5. But I need to be sure before I start digging deeper.

Any ideas how can I at least figure out what exactly goes wrong?

*EDIT*: More verbose server side log (DEBUG1):

```
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25465]: debug1: Forked child 25512.
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: Connection from --- port 55088 on --- port 22
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_4.3
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4* compat 0x00000000
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u2
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 104/65534 [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:11 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "myuser"
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "--myip--"
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: Connection closed by --myip-- [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: do_cleanup
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
Apr  1 13:19:12 host-07 sshd[25512]: debug1: Killing privsep child 25513
```

Comment: You need detailed logs from the server.  This may involve putting the daemon into debug mode and.or overhauling its syslog setup.

Comment: Done the more verbose log.

Comment: @confused-demon your public file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` should be `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or whatever key you are using. The `~/.ssh` directory must have `700` permissions as suggested by Jeff.

Comment: This is already so. I have eliminated problem with permissions in the beginning. Why do you think the issue is in that?

Comment: @confused-demon Please show what output `ls -lZd ~/.ssh  && ls -lZ ~/.ssh/` is showing.  Again your permission of `700` on the file is wrong and that's why you are having this problem

Comment: Ok, you wouldn't believe what stupid was the problem. Because I have written in .ssh/config IdentityFile in quotes. Thanks for help. So in the end it all again squared to the key file, hell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have root, run sshd in the foreground & in debug mode with `sshd -D -d`. You'll need to stop the sshd daemon first.  The server gives much more specific info on why a key fails.

You mention the file is 0700.  What's .ssh?  It must also be 0700.

Comment: Also 0700. I've made a more verbose log, but unfortunately I still cannot parse out any clue for me. Can you look, please?

Answer (score 0):

In case it might help, I met with a similar issue where I cannot log in via ssh neither, debug message looks similar

I do try to run `pam_rally2 -r --user ${username}` to reset failure count, but it still fails. Then I memorize that I have switched distro to `focal` and upgrade *libc* and etc...

A re-install `ssh` does solve the issue in the end...